# How do I make a chroot clone of my [current setup] like after a fresh install

Tags: chroot, debootstrap

Where I am...

I know that I

> debootstrap trusty /chroot-dir

and then I...

> mount --bind /dev /chroot-dir/dev && mount --bind /proc /chroot-dir/proc

and then

> cat /etc/apt/sources.list > /chroot-dir/etc/apt/sources.list

AFter that: Connection issues.
Hostname? dunno...

Comment: Did you copy the `/etc/resolv.conf` file of the base system to the chroot? It can be done by the same way the sources.list was copied.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the next steps at [the debootstrap wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot)